# Stored procedure to return a table with its name

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Can I return a table with its name in a stored procedure?

Comment: Please, don't use the `sql` and `server` tags separately - use the `sql-server` tag instead - thank you!!

Comment: Could you add example input and output for your procedure?

Answer (score 1):

No (assuming I understand YASQ)

There is no `ThisTable()` type function

It'd be a constant like this

```
SELECT 'ThisTable' AS CurrentTableName FROM ThisTable^
```

Answer (score 1):

As @gbn says, it is not possible to "query" what table names are used. You can return them as constants. But the table names are still returned to the client. I can't say that for sure for every kind of client but here is an example using ADO.

Here is the sample setup.

```
create table Tab1(Tab1ID int, Name varchar(10))
create table Tab2(Tab2ID int, Name varchar(10), Tab1ID int)

insert into Tab1 values(1, 'Name1')
insert into Tab2 values(1, 'Name2', 1)
insert into Tab2 values(2, 'Name2', 1)
```

The query

```
select *
from Tab1
  inner join Tab2
    on Tab1.Tab1ID = Tab2.Tab1ID
```

Result

```
Tab1ID      Name       Tab2ID      Name       Tab1ID
----------- ---------- ----------- ---------- -----------
1           Name1      1           Name2      1
1           Name1      2           Name2      1
```

In this case there are two tables used. Looking at what is actually returned to the client (using ADO) you will see this (converted to xml).

```
<xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
    xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
    xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
    xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
<s:Schema id='RowsetSchema'>
    <s:ElementType name='row' content='eltOnly' rs:updatable='true'>
        <s:AttributeType name='Tab1ID' rs:number='1' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='zz'
             rs:basetable='Tab1' rs:basecolumn='Tab1ID'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='int' dt:maxLength='4' rs:precision='10' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='Name' rs:number='2' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='zz' rs:basetable='Tab1'
             rs:basecolumn='Name'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='10'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='Tab2ID' rs:number='3' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='zz'
             rs:basetable='Tab2' rs:basecolumn='Tab2ID'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='int' dt:maxLength='4' rs:precision='10' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='c3' rs:name='Name' rs:number='4' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='zz'
             rs:basetable='Tab2' rs:basecolumn='Name'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='10'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name='c4' rs:name='Tab1ID' rs:number='5' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true' rs:basecatalog='zz'
             rs:basetable='Tab2' rs:basecolumn='Tab1ID'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='int' dt:maxLength='4' rs:precision='10' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:extends type='rs:rowbase'/>
    </s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
    <z:row Tab1ID='1' Name='Name1' Tab2ID='1' c3='Name2' c4='1'/>
    <z:row Tab1ID='1' Name='Name1' Tab2ID='2' c3='Name2' c4='1'/>
</rs:data>
</xml>
```

The data is returned in the `rs:data` tag. In the `s:Schema` you find all columns returned with some meta data about the column including the `rs:basetable` that contain the name of the table you are querying. You can use the [Recordset Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the base table name for each column in the result set.

Comment: @Martin - The xml is from `Recordset.Save('filename', adPersistXML)`.

Answer (score 0):

Look up OUTPUT parameters and RETURN values.  A stored procedure can select data from a table, assign parameter values that can be fed back to the calling procedure and referenced there by name, and can also return a value to the calling procedure.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262499

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx